# Creating a Beamer Option to Increment Presentation On Next Page

Tags: beamer

I watched a Beamer presentation yesterday where each new slide slid content from the top off the page and included new content on the bottom. It took a while to get used to, but when I did I found it quite helpful. Not all of my talks would work well in this format, but some would and I would like to know an efficient way to do it. I asked the speaker and he hard-coded everything (as in, he cut and pasted the content). I tried to make a less painful solution.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty %removes from controls from bottom right

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<+-+(2)>{\frametitle{Frame Title 1}
\begin{theorem}[1]
These are the hypotheses of this amazingly important theorem, which we can call Theorem 1. Following these hypotheses, comes the amazing conclusion. Aren't you impressed?
\end{theorem}
}
\only<+-+(2)>{
\begin{theorem}[2]
These are the hypotheses of this amazingly important theorem, which we can call Theorem 2. Following these hypotheses, comes the amazing conclusion. Aren't you impressed?
\end{theorem}
}
\only<+-+(3)>{
\begin{theorem}[3]
These are the hypotheses of this amazingly important theorem, which we can call Theorem 3. Following these hypotheses, comes the amazing conclusion. Aren't you impressed?
\end{theorem}
}
\only<+->{\frametitle{Frame Title 2}
\begin{theorem}[4]
These are the hypotheses of this amazingly important theorem, which we can call Theorem 4. Following these hypotheses, comes the amazing conclusion. Aren't you impressed?
\end{theorem}
}
\only<+->{
\begin{theorem}[5]
These are the hypotheses of this amazingly important theorem, which we can call Theorem 5. Following these hypotheses, comes the amazing conclusion. Aren't you impressed?
\end{theorem}
}

\only<+->{\frametitle{Frame Title 3}
\alert<6>{Here comes an itemized list:}
}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item This is the first bullet point 
\item That's the second one
\item The third bullet point
\item The final bullet point
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This returns the output
[image: Incremental Presentation]

The positives are that I do not have to repeat any of the text and I figured out how to change the `frametitle` when appropriate. The downside is that I have to very carefully use the `\only` command each block, and adding new content often requires renumbering things quite a bit. What I would like is to put each text block (i.e., what I want to appear next on the slide) into its own environment and then for tex to compute the size of the block and automatically put only as much content on the screen as would fit (something like `allowframebreaks` but more nuanced) as well as a convenient way to change the `frametitle` where appropriate. I'm not super concerned about how it interacts with `section` and `subsection` commands as I don't typically use those in my slides, but bonus points if it is compatible with those too.

Is this just too ambitious?